# Open source tool to extract ActionScript from FlashMovies

Tags: flash, security

Is there an Open source tool to extract ActionScript from Flash movies, ideally written in (or consumed by) C#

I just did a search and found http://www.nowrap.de/flare.html, but the source code is not available.

I need this so that I can allow the security review of Flash & ActionScript using the [OWASP O2 Platform](http://www.o2platform.com)

Comment: ... I love this ! A security consultant being told to download a torrent illegally from a person whose bio says Live to hack, hack to live. Noice. As good as your motives are... to the general public this is very unethical. Example : [New Beijing Summer Olympics event: software piracy](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/news/2008/03/new-beijing-summer-olympics-event-software-piracy.ars)

Comment: Yeah I agree, I'm not going to follow that link (to the pirated copy) since I don't agree with those practices. And in fact, there days, most pirated software is riddle with malware.

Comment: @phwd  I also commonly use full disclosure with wormable exploit code.  Don't trust anyone on SO,  especially the person with the most up votes for security answers :o).

Comment: @Dinis Cruz If you don't have an Anti-Virus then you have bigger problems on your hands.  But thats fine you can always buy a SWF Decompiler.

Comment: @Dinis Cruz Your totally right about my profile, I had to update it.

Comment: @The Rook Sweet ! it makes more sense now :D it would be best though if this type of request went private though

Comment: @phwd i wish there where private messages,  that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

check out [swftools.org](http://swftools.org) -- there's an app in there called *swfdump* which is the closest I've gotten to solving this same issue. It's not *C#*, but it's what I got..